How to turn 1 image into a 125 images to make up a 5 second (25 fps) end-roll
Continuing from my earlier question.
I realized that FFmpeg can only perform 1D transitions, e.g. it cannot do an image blur which is a 2D transition
I'm looking for a CLI tool that can perform a gradual gray scale and gradual blur from 1 single frame, and generate the transition over X frames, in this case, 125.
I have seen

ppmfade - too limited, can't blur
convert - unsure how to make it fit 125 frames

Any other methods? Thank you.

Update: I have the below code, but it is ugly, the blurring occurs in steps/bands rather than gradually. And $strength does not seem to accept decimals, only integers from 1-8. Is there a way to smooth this out?
for filename in out*.png; do

    suffix="${filename##*[0-9]}"
    number="${filename%"$suffix"}"
    number="${number##*[!0-9]}"

    integer=$(expr $number + 0)
    strength=$((integer * 8 / 125))

    echo $strength $filename
    convert $filename -blur 0x$strength end-$number.png
done


After some experimentation, I realized ImageMagick's convert was able to accept a $strength from 0 to 60 (possibly even higher) and that made it smooth enough for me.
for filename in out*.png; do

    suffix="${filename##*[0-9]}"
    number="${filename%"$suffix"}"
    number="${number##*[!0-9]}"

    integer=$(expr $number + 0)
    strength=$((integer * 60 / 125))

    echo $strength $filename
    convert $filename -blur 0x$strength end-$number.png
done

